# Como colocar fundo branco/transparente na imagem png que esta com o fundo preto

Tags: imagem, lazarus

Estou utilizando este código em lazarus mas na hora de salvar ele mostra uma parte preta como o da imagem, queria que ficasse branca/transparente. Testei umas maneiras e não deu certo.

```
  procedure TformMain.btSalvarImagemClick(Sender: TObject);
  var
  bmp: TBitmap;
  R: TRect;
  png : TPortableNetworkGraphic;
  begin
  // bmp, png
  bmp := TBitmap.Create;
  png := TPortableNetworkGraphic.Create;
  try
  // bmp
  if SavePictureDialog1.Execute then
  begin
  R := Rect(500, 500, BarcodeQR1.Width, BarcodeQR1.Height);
  bmp.SetSize(600, 600);
  bmp.Canvas.Brush.Color := clWhite;
  bmp.Canvas.FillRect®;
  BarcodeQR1.PaintOnCanvas(bmp.Canvas, R);
  png.Assign(bmp);
  png.SaveToFile(SavepictureDialog1.Filename);
  end;
  finally
  bmp.Free;
  png.Free;
  end;
  end;`
```

[image: QrCode]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consegui

`procedure TformMain.btSalvarImagem1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  bmp: TBitmap;
  R: TRect;
  png : TPortableNetworkGraphic;
begin
  // bmp, png
  bmp := TBitmap.Create;
  png := TPortableNetworkGraphic.Create;
  try
 // bmp
 if SavePictureDialog1.Execute then
 begin
   BarcodeQR2.Height := 600;
   BarcodeQR2.Width := 600;
   R := Rect(0, 0, BarcodeQR2.Width, BarcodeQR2.Height);
   bmp.SetSize(BarcodeQR2.Width, BarcodeQR2.Height);
   bmp.Canvas.Brush.Color := clWhite;
   bmp.Canvas.FillRect(R);
   BarcodeQR2.PaintOnCanvas(bmp.Canvas, R);
   png.Assign(bmp);
   png.SaveToFile(SavepictureDialog1.Filename);
   BarcodeQR2.Height := 120;
   BarcodeQR2.Width := 105;
 end;
 finally
   bmp.Free;
   png.Free;
 end;
 end;`

[image: QRCode]

Answer (score 1):

Encontrei essa resposta, tente colocar isto no código:

```
 bmp.TransparentColor := bmp.Canvas.Pixels[0,0];
```

Em seguida coloque insto

```
 bmp.Transparent := True
```

Comment: Ainda não deu certo

Answer (score 1):

Substitua o trecho:

```
  png.Assign(bmp);
  png.SaveToFile(SavepictureDialog1.Filename);
```

por:

```
  png.PixelFormat := pf32bit;
  png.Transparent := True;
  png.TransparentColor := clWhite;
  png.Assign(bmp);
  png.SaveToFile(SavepictureDialog1.Filename);
```

Comment: O estranho que se eu abrir o site depois de salvar a imagem e dar um ctrl + v a imagem aparece certinha, mas salvando normal não

Comment: @JacksonFelipeMagnabosco, tente abrir a imagem salva com outro software que não seja o visualizador do windows.